# Are Euclidean domains first-order axiomatizable in just the language of rings?

Tags: ring-theory, model-theory, euclidean-domain

The notion of an Euclidean domain is defined using the auxiliary machinery of a Euclidean function. But, I wonder, is that auxiliary machinery actually needed? More precisely, in the language $\{+,-,*,0,1\}$ of rings, is the class $K$ of those rings which are Euclidean domains, first-order axiomatizable, and if so, is it finitely first-order axiomatizable? Also, if it is not first-order axiomatizable, is the first-order theory of the class $K$ finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: I think a nontrivial ultrapower of the integers is not a Euclidean domain.

Comment: I wonder if the first-order theory might be just the theory of gcd domains.

Comment: @DanielSchepler very nice question! (although I think it should probably be about Bézout domains rather than gcd domains? because the property that every finitely generated ideal is principal is first-order expressible)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I think Cohn discusses that in *Bezout rings and their subrings*

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for the reference, I will have a look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the class of Euclidean domains is not elementary.

Let $\mathcal{Z}$ be any nonstandard model of the theory of the ring of integers (e.g. a nontrivial ultrapower). By overspill, there are instances of the Euclidean algorithm implemented internally to $\mathcal{Z}$ which are nonstandardly long; these prevent any genuine Euclidean function for $\mathcal{Z}$ for existing, since they would force any such function to assign an infinite value to any of the numbers occurring in this instance.

Comment: +1; maybe it's worth additionally noting that a non-standard model of true arithmetic cannot even be a UFD, let alone a PID or euclidean domain